# Preventing DoS Attacks on NFC

Tags: denial-of-service, nfc, countermeasure

There are some attack scenarios on NFC. These include e.g. Data modification, data insertion, relay attacks and DoS attacks. Just to name a few.

While some of these attack scenarios are more likely than others, I wonder how to prevent a DoS attack on NFC. The key issue in the DoS attack on NFC devices is that many requests are sent and a device is overloaded, or a smartphone reads out a bad or infected tag and thus gets into a boot loop (or it just reboots or opens any applications ... ). In the literature, it is said that DoS attacks are easy to detect, this would require an active device to scan the RF field for further signals. Since the DoS attack also requires a higher performance, a DoS attack can be detected.

The problem at this point is that it is nice to see that an attack is taking place, but the question is how to prevent a DoS attack on NFC. In the literature, I have not found much in this regard, so I hope for some answers here, on the subject.

Comment: Resource consumption by flooding (layer 3/4)  can be prevented quite well by implementing resource limits on the device, so a crashing  rate limiting, lockout periods, etc. Crashing code in the OS or even higher up triggered by sending a single malicious packet (layer 7) is much harder to prevent, and can only really be fixed by something like sandboxing everything that interacts with NFC data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That sounds plausible, my question that would follow this is: how do you know that? Can you name one or more sources where to read it?

Comment: Because these concepts are extensively studied in web servers, and I don't see any reason why these specific properties would not translate to NFC